# PostgreSQL on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: django, git, postgresql

Please i used the django-girls django tutorial created my first django project but used postgreSQL database instead and i pushed it to my repository on github. I tried to host it on pythonanywhere.com but i got an error. I researched on the error and found out that i have to upgrade to a paid account to use postgreSQL. I deleted the repository from github and even started the django project again this time using the default SQLlite3 and then i pushed it to github. When i tried to push it to pythonanywhere.com, i got the same postgreSQL error. Please i want to know how i can change the database back to SQLlite3 because pythonanywhere.com is still recognising the postgreSQL. I hope my question is understood. Thanks

Comment: The database is configured in the settings. If you get an error then either the settings are wrong, or python anywhere isn't using the code you think it is. Your question is too vague to get more help on Stack Overflow, because you have not shown your code or the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks. I have been able to get a solution.